# Deviance of a regression model

Tags: r, regression, deviance

The deviance of a model is defined as:
$D =  -2(loglikelihood(model) - loglikelihood(saturated.model)) $

So I tried to compare the result of this formula with the output of the deviance() function with different models:

Linear regression model:

```
> ?cats
> m1=lm(Hwt~Bwt+Sex,data=cats)
> m1.saturated=lm(Hwt~factor(1:nrow(cats)),data=cats)
> deviance(m1)
[1] 299
> sum(residuals(m1)^2)
[1] 299
> deviance(m1.saturated)
[1] 0
> as.numeric(-2*(logLik(m1)-logLik(m1.saturated)))
[1] Inf
```

299 $\neq $ Inf
Something is wrong

GLM: Poisson regression

```
> x = rnorm(10)
> y = rpois(10,lam=exp(1 + 2*x))
> m2 = glm(formula = y ~ x, family = poisson)
> m2.saturated <- glm(y ~ factor(1:10),family=poisson)
> deviance(m2) 
[1] 14
> deviance(m2.saturated) 
[1] 4.5e-10
> as.numeric(-2*(logLik(m2)-logLik(m2.saturated))) 
[1] 14
```

14 = 14
Ok, it works!

GLM: Gamma regression

```
 > cement <- read.table("cement.dat", col.names = c("time","resistance"), dec = ",") 
 > attach(cement)
 > m3 <- glm(resistance ~ I(1/time), family = Gamma)
 > m3.saturated <- glm(resistance ~ factor(1:nrow(cement)), family = Gamma)
 > deviance(m3)
 [1] 0.16
 > deviance(m3.saturated)
 [1] 9.3e-17
 > as.numeric(-2*(logLik(m3)-logLik(m3.saturated)))
 [1] 758
```

0.16 $\neq $ 758
There must be a mistake somewhere

Shouldn't the results be the same?

Comment: For code snippets I would recommend leaving out the `>` prompt and instead commenting-out the console output with `#`. Makes it much easier to copy and paste!

Comment: Are you sure you have defined your `logLik()` function correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to understand how the dispersion parameter should be included in the formula to compute the deviance of a linear model from its log-likelihood, and I cannot find any reference in books about GLMs. This is really a mystery to me. Even if this is quite a basic point, the fact that nobody answered seems to indicate it's obscure for many people...

My small contribution: since the log-likelihood of the saturated model is Inf, we may also start with a simpler question, and compute the difference in deviance between two non-saturated models. But this still doesn't work:

```
library(MASS)
data(cats)
m0=lm(Hwt~Bwt,data=cats)
m1=lm(Hwt~Bwt+Sex,data=cats)
deviance(m1)-deviance(m0)
#[1] -0.1548002
as.numeric(-2*(logLik(m1)-logLik(m0)))
#[1] -0.07443916
```

It seems obvious to me that the dispersion parameter should be included in the formula, but how? For a start, there are two estimations of the dispersion, one for m1 and one for m2.

Comment: Since this wasn't obvious, the code from the OP as well as mine rely on R's built-in functions, which give correct answers AFAICT (e.g. they are the same as Stata).